# Displaying arrows in the VTK.js library

Tags: javascript, vtk.js

I want to display arrows in the VTK.js library, and scale their magnitude with a known value. The application is to map stress fields on finite elements. However, I can't any such function within the current library. Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply using text containing a single arrow character like →

The magnitude would be the size of the font.